# Pthread_create function in C11

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to create a `pthread` with `Pthread_create` :

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *worker(void *arg) {
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t p1, p2;

    Pthread_create(&p1, NULL, worker, NULL);
    Pthread_create(&p2, NULL, worker, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

> clang -Wall -std=c11 -pthread thread.c -o thread

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: `"_Pthread_create"`:

```
thread.c:13:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Pthread_create' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        Pthread_create(&p1, NULL, worker, NULL);
        ^
1 warning generated.
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Pthread_create", referenced from:
      _main in thread-3223a1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Nothing changes after altering to `-std=c99`

What's wrong with my code?

> clang --version

```
clang version 3.8.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 68170291648f0112957a8b3d6912a1a1fed81965) (http://llvm.org/git/llvm.git 92ca4a0cd38e8f17e62ecf6e93a44c8ecf098b12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

PS: **I don't want to change to C++** since I'm doing exercise on a book of operating system(UNIX C environment).

Comment: pLEASE use lower-caps `p`..hope you got the point...:)

Comment: @SouravGhosh I see and now the program works. But at the beginning I saw `Pthread_create` in this book http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/intro.pdf. Is it a mistake?

Comment: Not likely, it may be correct. Notice the `#include "common.h"` part?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Oh, okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates the linker is not able to find the symbol Pthread_create. is this pthread_create  or Pthread_create? You also need to link the library with "-lpthread".

Comment: `-lpthread ` is not required

Comment: you mean -pthread is sufficient when using clang? "-l" option is normally used with many compilers, particularly on many UNIX/LINUX flavours..